# beginner c++ textbook disagrees with actual output I get when compiling math equations

Tags: c++

Hi so the following are questions from my hw this week, I answered them in accordance with the material I found in my textbook but because we are graded extremely harsh in this class I thought I'd run them through a compiler to see if my answers were right. However when I run them in a c++ compiler I can't get the pow, ceil, or floor functions to return a floating point, they only return integers which disagrees with what my book says they should return??? I showed what my answers to the hw should be according to the book, and in parentheses what happens when i compile them.

question;             what my book
                     says the 
                     answer
                     should be;                 (what the compiler shows);

A) pow(2,3);          8.0;              (my book says pow only returns a floating
                                       point but this only returns an integer,
                                       even when I change the function to be 
                                         pow(2.0,3.0) I only get 8);

B) fabs(-3.5);        3.5;                (this one works, it returns 3.5);

C) sqrt(pow(3,2));    2.8;                (returns 2.82843, how am I supposed to
                                         know how many decimals to put out?);

D) 7 / abs(-2);       3;                    (this one works);

E) ceil(5.8);         6.0;                 (only returns the integer 6);

F) floor(5.8);        5.0;                   (only returns the integer 5);

Comment: Please show your code. Could you be writing something like int a = pow(2, 3);?

Comment: You should show the code you're using to test these.

Comment: 1) You don't "run them in a c++ compiler" - you compile/link/assemble your source, and then you run the resulting program.

Comment: In any system of arithmetic, 8 == 8.0. They're the same number. The only difference is how many decimal points you ask for when you print it out.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have described, everything is working as expected. You haven't included the code you've written so this is somewhat of a guess - but you are asking the computer to print out the value of some numbers. You are getting `8` but you are expecting `8.0`. Neither you nor the computer are wrong. You just need to ask the computer to print out decimal point values, even if the number you're asking to print is exactly an integer.

Answer (score 0):

> Question; what my book says the answer should be; (what the compiler shows);

The compiler doesn't show anything about types. (Well, it can, but you have to poke deep. For example, make it generate assembly, or use a trick that shows the type as a compiler error.)

Presumably you are basing your thoughts on what you see printed. For example, consider this C++11 program:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
   auto pow_2_3 = std::pow(2,3);
   // int eight {pow_2_3};  // Compilation error.
   std::cout << pow_2_3 << '\n';
}
```

This prints "8" (not 8.0). Does that mean the type is an integer? Of course not. That "8" just means the default formatting is stripping the trailing zeros, and the decimal point as well.

You'll get a compilation error if you uncomment the commented-out line because a double cannot be narrowed to an integer. Not even if it's exact, and not even if it's known at compile time. The type of `pow_2_3` is a double, just as the standard specifies. If `std::pow(2,3)` actually is an integer on your computer with your compiler, then you have a non-compliant compiler.

The same is true for `std::ceil` and `std::floor`. They return doubles, not integers.